# Warnings from hyperref whenever using \part{} with amsbook

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, amsbook

### Previous Fixes to Hyperref Warnings

There are roughly 100 questions on `hyperref` warnings about using certain tokens in `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` for *any* document class.  Those tokens cause problems in pdf bookmarking and are corrected with `\texorpdfstring`. For example,

- `\chapter{Find $A$}` is fixed with `\chapter{Find \texorpdfstring{$A$}{A}}`
- `\author{Name\\ foo@bar.baz}` is fixed with `\author{Name\texorpdfstring{\\ foo@bar.baz}{}}`

### My Question

I get warnings when *anything* is placed inside `\part` but only if the `amsbook` document class is used.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\part{Test}
\end{document}
```

produces these warnings

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\leavevmode@ifvmode' on input line 7.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                \kern 5.0pt
(hyperref)                replaced by space on input line 7.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\noindent' on input line 7.
```

Using `\texorpdfstring` does nothing.  However, changing **either** the document class (e.g., `book`,`amsart`, etc.) **or** changing the sectioning (e.g.,`\chapter`,`\section`, etc.) eliminates the warnings.

### Added

Clearly the `\part` command is trying to insert a newpage (and other things) under `amsbook` and this is what is bothering `hyperref`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it probably makes sense to handle \enspace in hyperref, but why on earth does amsbook insert a \noindent here: `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname\ \thepart. \protect\enspace\protect\noindent#1}`??

Comment: It is just a warning but after years of ignoring them, I have embarked on examining my log file and addressing even harmless warnings.  Consequently, I have eliminated a lot of conflicting code (from my still growing 400+ page document).  Feels good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

`hyperref` is making the outline/bookmark text for PDF, This has to be plain text so hyperref removes/simplifies any tex constructs. Some commands it "knows" Sometimes it is given text alternatives via `\texorpdfstring` but in other cases it simply drops the unknown command with the warning you show. (The original commands are still used for typesetting the heading.)

Unfortunately `amsbook` is using some unexpected (and in the case of `\noindent`, completely useless) commands in setting up `\part`, so triggers this warning.

This patches the command so `hyperref` understands it. If `amsbook` is updated so the patch fails, an undefined `\ERROR` message will be  given, hopefully you can simply remove the patch as this will have been fixed at source.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part{\protect\enspace\protect\noindent}{\hspace{.5em}}{}{\ERROR}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\part{Test}
\end{document}
```